# SQL: Select entries with the biggest amount of "reviews" and then order the result by the highest average rate of them

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I have the following code:

```
select
  count(restaurants.id) as restaurant_count,
  `restaurants`.*,
  round(AVG(restaurant_reviews.rate), 1) as rate
from
  `restaurants`
  inner join `restaurant_reviews` on `restaurant_reviews`.`restaurant_id` = `restaurants`.`id`
group by
  `restaurants`.`id`
order by
  `restaurant_count` desc
limit
  3
```

This returns me something like that:

```
restaurant_count, id,     name     , rate
      25        , 12, Restaurant 12, 4.6
      22        , 08, Restaurant 08, 4.1
      17        , 19, Restaurant 19, 4.4
```

That means it returns the top 3 restaurants that have the biggest amount of `restaurant_reviews` (which number of reviews is showed at `restaurant_count`).
What I would like to achieve is, after that, order these results by the rate, at a descending order. Ex:

```
restaurant_count, id,     name     , rate
      25        , 12, Restaurant 12, 4.6
      17        , 19, Restaurant 19, 4.4
      22        , 08, Restaurant 08, 4.1
```

How could I do that? I wrote all in SQL, but laravel query builder is also welcome.

I tried simply change `order by` to:

```
order by
  `restaurant_count` desc,
  `rate` desc
limit
  3
```

But it will order first by `restaurant_count`, and after this will only order the entries that has the same amount of `restaurant_count`, by rate. That means that every restaurant that has the biggest `restaurant_count` will always be at a higher position, no matter it's rate. And that is problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
select r.*
from (select count(*) as review_count, r.*, round(avg(rr.rate), 1) as rate
      from restaurants r join
           restaurant_reviews rr
           on rr.restaurant_id = r.id
      group by r.id
      order by review_count desc
      limit 3
     ) r
order by rate desc;
```

Comment: Thanks! just a small fix: instead of `avg(r.rate)`, which returns an error, use `avg(rr.rate)`